# Merge two multi-dimensional arrays by matching on a chosen column and returns a new array with all rows and columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have mostly worked in `vba` and am starting to move to Google sheets.

I am have been trying to write a function that matches two multi-dimensional arrays on a chosen column and returns a new merged array based on the matches Where there are matches, and the not-matched rows from the first array where there were no matches

I have been able so far to get a result of the matched rows `only` and have failed to figure out how to get the not-matched rows as well

In real life setting arr and brr can have hundreds of rows and dozens of columns and do not have the same dimensions

I have

```
function test() {
  arr =[
       [Client Name, Header1, Header2, Id], 
       [Name1, info1, different-info1, id-1], 
       [Name2, info2, different-info2, esi-6], 
       [Name3, info3, different-info3, id-3], 
       [Name4, info4, different-info4, esi-1], 
       [Name5, , different-info5, id-5], 
       [Name6, info6, different-info6, esi-3], 
       [Name7, info7, different-info7, id-7], 
       [Name8, info8, different-info8, id-8], 
       [Name9, info9, different-info9, esi-5]
       ]

  brr =[ 
       [ID, Company-Name, File Number, Info, Different Info], 
       [esi-1, Acme-1, f123456, , different-sting1], 
       [esi-2, Acme-2, f123457, string1, different-sting2], 
       [esi-3, Acme-3, f123458, string2, different-sting3], 
       [esi-4, Acme-4, f123459, string3, different-sting4], 
       [esi-5, Acme-5, f123460, string4, ], 
       [esi-6, Acme-6, f123461, string5, ]
       ]

  //Header to Match on
  const headerMatch = "Id"
  
  //Index of matched header for arr
  const aIndex = arr[0].map(v => v.toLowerCase()).indexOf(headerMatch.toLowerCase());
  
  //Index of matched header for brr
  const bIndex = brr[0].map(v => v.toLowerCase()).indexOf(headerMatch.toLowerCase());
  
  //The array of merged data from arr and brr matched on "Id"
  const result = arr.map(a => brr.filter(b => b[bIndex].toLowerCase() === a[aIndex].toLowerCase()).map(b => [...a,b[0],b[2],b[1]])).flatMap(a => a); 
  
  return result
}
```

```
result =
[[Client Name, Header1, Header2, Id, ID, File Number, Company-Name], 
[Name2, info2, different-info2, esi-6, esi-6, f123461, Acme-6], 
[Name4, info4, different-info4, esi-1, esi-1, f123456, Acme-1], 
[Name6, info6, different-info6, esi-3, esi-3, f123458, Acme-3], 
[Name9, info9, different-info9, esi-5, esi-5, f123460, Acme-5]]
```

```
Needed Result =
[[Client Name, Header1, Header2, Id, ID, File Number, Company-Name], 
[Name1, info1, different-info1, id-1, , , ], 
[Name2, info2, different-info2, esi-6, esi-6, f123461, Acme-6], 
[Name3, info3, different-info3, id-3, , , ], 
[Name4, info4, different-info4, esi-1, esi-6, f123461, Acme-6], 
[Name5, , different-info5, id-5, , , ], 
[Name6, info6, different-info6, esi-3, esi-3, f123458, Acme-3], 
[Name7, info7, different-info7, id-7, , , ], 
[Name8, info8, different-info8, id-8, , , ], 
[Name9, info9, different-info9, esi-5, esi-5, f123460, Acme-5]]
```

I want to keep this method because of how you can chose what is returned, it is wonderfully generalized

You can return all columns from both arrays `[...a,...b]` or you can pick only the columns you want returned `[...a,b[0],b[2],b[1]]`

I am posting images as I think they more clearly show what I mean

arr
[arr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGjVM.png)

brr
[brr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH6XF.png)

result (what I get)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm4fs.png)

result Needed
[result Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4ij0.png)

Google sheet with data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2vv4I3qeZgs0sCdguxY3clQdyBprG12cV9VDBPHxLc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: please add valid data (ready to copy) and the wanted result in text form.

Comment: I have add a google sheet with data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could collect the second array data with their keys in an object and map the first array.

```js
function leftJoin(a, b, key, columns) {
    key = key.toLowerCase();
  
    const
        aIndex = a[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === key),
        bIndex = b[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === key),
        temp = b.slice(1).reduce((r, items, i) => (r[items[bIndex]] = items, r), {});
        
    return a.map((items, i) => [
        ...items,
        ...columns.map(
            j => (i
                ? temp[items[aIndex]] || Array(b[0].length).fill('')
                : b[0])[j]                
        )
    ]);
}

const
    a = [['Client Name', 'Header1', 'Header2', 'Id'], ['Name1', 'info1', 'different-info1', 'id-1'], ['Name2', 'info2', 'different-info2', 'esi-6'], ['Name3', 'info3', 'different-info3', 'id-3'], ['Name4', 'info4', 'different-info4', 'esi-1'], ['Name5', undefined, 'different-info5', 'id-5'], ['Name6', 'info6', 'different-info6', 'esi-3'], ['Name7', 'info7', 'different-info7', 'id-7'], ['Name8', 'info8', 'different-info8', 'id-8'], ['Name9', 'info9', 'different-info9', 'esi-5']],
    b = [['ID', 'Company-Name', 'File Number', 'Info', 'Different Info'], ['esi-1', 'Acme-1', 'f123456', undefined, 'different-sting1'], ['esi-2', 'Acme-2', 'f123457', 'string1', 'different-sting2'], ['esi-3', 'Acme-3', 'f123458', 'string2', 'different-sting3'], ['esi-4', 'Acme-4', 'f123459', 'string3', 'different-sting4'], ['esi-5', 'Acme-5', 'f123460', 'string4', undefined], ['esi-6', 'Acme-6', 'f123461', 'string5', undefined]];    

console.log(leftJoin(a, b, 'id', [0, 2, 1]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina, thank you for your assistance. the function is matching and posting back on the entire arrays in the proper way! But Javascript is vary new to me so I do not see how  choose/limit what columns to post-back as in my original function

Comment: what columns do you want?

Comment: I need it to be dynamic as in my the original attempt as my needs change per project

Comment: Here:  `const result = arr.map(a => brr.filter(b => b[bIndex].toLowerCase() === a[aIndex].toLowerCase()).map(b => [...a,b[0],b[2],b[1]])).flatMap(a => a);`  this part: `[...a,b[0],b[2],b[1]]`